# Умножить все численные значения объекта

Tags: javascript

Как умножить все численные свойства объекта на 2, но результат `[object object]`.

```js
let obj = {
  w: 200,
  c: "red",
  h: 300,
  q: "aqua"
}


function f(obj) {
  for (let bazm in obj) {

    if (typeof obj[bazm] == 'number') {
      obj[bazm] *= 2;
    }

  }
  document.body.innerHTML += obj;
}

f(obj);
```

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.stringify(obj)`

```js
let obj = {
  w: 200,
  c: "red",
  h: 300,
  q: "aqua"

};


function f(obj) {
  for (let bazm in obj) {

    if (typeof obj[bazm] == 'number') {
      obj[bazm] *= 2;
    }

  }
  document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj);
}

f(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя присвоить XML (HTML) документу  объект, данные которого не представленны в виде строки или числа.

Поэтому можно представить объект в виде строки [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
let obj = {
    w: 200,
    c: "red",
    h: 300,
    q: "aqua"
}

Object.keys(obj)
.filter(i => typeof obj[i] == 'number')
.map(i => obj[i] *= 2);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

---

Или напрямую сделать вывод данных из объекта.

```js
let obj = {
    w: 200,
    c: "red",
    h: 300,
    q: "aqua"
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(i => document.body.innerHTML += `${i}: ${obj[i]}; `);
```

Comment: Вместо `.map(i => obj[i] *= 2)` лучше `forEach`. Семантически мап не меняет, а возвращает, и не должен зависить от количества/порядка вызовов.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov согласен